# how to transpose data in PySpark using dynamic function

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There will be multiple columns and multiple rows.

```
-------+------+-------+
|Product|Amount|Country|
+-------+------+-------+
|Banana |1000  |USA    |
|Carrots|1500  |USA    |
|Beans  |1600  |USA    |
|Orange |2000  |USA    |
|Orange |2000  |USA    |
|Banana |400   |China  |
|Carrots|1200  |China  |
|Beans  |1500  |China  |
|Orange |4000  |China  |
|Banana |2000  |Canada |
|Carrots|2000  |Canada |
|Beans  |2000  |Mexico |
```

Input will 5 columns and 3 rows and
output will 3 rows and 5 columns

I am expecting that i need dynamic function that will take dataframe as input and will automatically will transpose data. we just need to call that dataframe in that function

Answer (score 1):

Within pyspark this would be the `.pivot()` function with the parameter being the column you want to pivot it by.

This data sample looks like the same one used here https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-pivot-and-unpivot-dataframe which showcases how to do what you're asking for

Edit: In order to use the `.pivot()` function you first need to aggregate the dataframe which is shown in the linked example

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupBy("Product").pivot("Country").sum("Amount").show()
```

Comment: can we create dynamic function for that so we just call dataframe in that function

Comment: Sure something like `def pivot_fn(group_by_cols, pivot_by_col, sum_by_col):`